# After market car stereos with iOS 4/iPod Out support?

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod, ios, audio

I have an iPod Touch that was upgraded to iOS 4.  I am sick of my FM transmitter, and am looking for an after-market car receiver for my 1998 Honda Civic with iPod support, but am concerned because of discussions like  [Topic : iOS 4 - Iphone 3GS - Alpine X303 - Not supported anymore](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=11723270).

Articles like [iPhone OS 4.0 paving way for Apple-branded car kit?](http://www.engadget.com/2010/04/13/iphone-os-4-0-paving-way-for-apple-branded-car-kit/) and the comments section of [Instant Expert: Secrets & Features of iOS 4](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/instant-expert-secrets-features-of-ios-4/) mention a feature called `iPod Out`.  Also, [iOS 4′s hidden “iPod Out” feature brings iPhone support to your car without the messy third party UI](http://www.mobilecrunch.com/2010/07/13/ios-4s-hidden-ipod-out-feature-brings-iphone-support-to-your-car-without-the-messy-third-party-ui/) talks about how BMW is announcing support.

Does anybody know of third party units ([Alpine](http://www.alpine-usa.com/product/category/ipod-iphone), [Kenwood](http://www.kenwoodusa.com/Car_Entertainment/In-Dash_CD_n_DVD_Receivers/1-DIN_CD_Receiver/), [JVC](http://mobile.jvc.com/ipod.jsp), etc) that have specific support for iPod Out?

I mainly listen to podcasts and audio books (and not music) on my commute.  One of the key features I want is the ability to use pause/resume controls on the receiver when I get a phone call.  Doing a "slide to unlock", then finding the pause button while driving isn't very safe, so I end up missing content.

Answer (score 2):

iPod Out, indeed, looks very cool ...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wbco58GnS9c

... but **is there any reason that a simple line-out cable wouldn't work**, at least until more companies hop on the iPod Out bandwagon? There appears to be a whole lot of nothing out there right now.

At the very least it's way better than the FM transmitters, which *really* suck.

Comment: I updated my question to address the line-out suggestion